# Keep 1 year data in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table called Inc_Hist and it contains data from last 3 years and i want to keep only 1 year worth of data and move remaining data into a different table Inc_Archive.

Table structure of Inc_hist

```
Inc_Num  Modified_Date
Inc01    3/4/2014
Inc02    11/2/2013
Inc03    2/1/2015
Inc04    6/3/2013
Inc05    5/3/2014
```

Output should be:

Inc_hist

```
Inc_Num  Modified_date
Inc01    3/4/2014
Inc03    2/1/2015
Inc05    5/3/2015
```

Inc_Archive

```
Inc_Num   Modified_date
Inc02     11/2/2013
Inc04     6/3/2013
```

Comment: Do you want data to move spontaneously, e.g. via a scheduled task that runs every 10 seconds? Do you want a trigger to move old data whenever new data is added? Do you want something you can run on demand before generating a report? Do you want someone to solve your problem with no evidence that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the year data by `DATEPART` function. This one gives you exact result.

```
 DECLARE @Inc_Hist TABLE(Inc_Num varchar(10), Modified_Date date)
DECLARE @Inc_Archive TABLE(Inc_Num varchar(10), Modified_Date date)

insert into @Inc_Hist (Inc_Num, Modified_Date)
Values 
('Inc01', '3/4/2014'),
('Inc02', '11/2/2013'),
('Inc03', '2/1/2015'),
('Inc04', '6/3/2013'),
('Inc05', '5/3/2014')

INSERT INTO @Inc_Archive (Inc_Num, Modified_Date)
select Inc_Num, Modified_Date from @Inc_Hist 
WHERE DATEPART(Y,Modified_Date) > DATEPART(Y,GETDATE())

DELETE @Inc_Hist
WHERE DATEPART(Y,Modified_Date) > DATEPART(Y,GETDATE())

SELECT Inc_Num, Modified_Date FROM @Inc_Hist
SELECT Inc_Num, Modified_Date FROM @Inc_Archive
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would also suggest wrapping the insert and delete in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in a single step, but you can first insert the data to archive table and then delete it from the history table:

```
INSERT INTO Inc_Archive(Inc_Num, Modified_Date)
SELECT Inc_Num, Modified_Date FROM Inc_Hist 
WHERE Modified_Date < @dateFrom    -- Define the date

DELETE FROM Inc_Hist 
WHERE Modified_Date < @dateFrom    -- Define the date
```

If you want to explicitly remove records older than 1 year from current date you can use functions `DATEADD` and `GETDATE`. Change `WHERE` condition to the following code:

```
WHERE Modified_Date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```